# Flex and Bison accept a line that contains only a comment

Tags: flex-lexer

The exercise 1.1 in flex and bison ask me to accept a line that contains only a comment.
Here is part of my .l file:

```
%{   
   #include"fb1-5.tab.h"
%}

%%

...
"//".* {  return COMMENT;}
\n     {  return EOL;}

%%
```

Then is my .y file:

```
%{ 
    #include <stdio.h> 
%}

....  // the token about the calculator

%token COMMENT
%token EOL

%%

....    // the rulse about the calculator

comment: COMMENT EOL { printf("%s",yytext);}

%%
```

When I run the project and input 
`//test`

outputs:

`error: syntax error`

Comment: You don't parse comments. They should be treated as white space by the lexer.

Comment: Thank! I know what you mean but I want to parse comments and print them.

Comment: Then you're not responding to the exercise. And it is a useful exercise. It does not ask you to print comments. It asks only whether the calculator accepts a line containing only a comment. You have found that it doesn't. How do you fix that? So here's a similar question: does the calculator accept blank lines? No? Is that a problem, in your opinion? How can you fix it? Is it the same fix?

Comment: @rici Thank you very much at beginning. I'm clear that the calculator should not accepts a line containing only a comment. What makes me confused is the "fix". I have no idea except get the comments. Look forward to your kind reply/advice.

Comment: I answered the question; maybe it will help. If you want to learn about how parsing works, you really need to take the time to try to understand what the parser and scanner rules really mean, and going through the exercises is a good way to improve your understanding. So I don't know if I've done you any favours here :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's clear that the calculator reports a syntax error if you enter a line containing only a comment. That's a problem, particularly with this simple implementation which fails as soon as a syntax error is encountered. (A real calculator would have to recover from the error. That's covered later in the book.)

But let's forget about comments. What if we just enter a blank line?

```
$ ./fb1-5

syntax error
$
```

It shouldn't take too much thought to see that these two problems are related. The scanner just removes comments from the input stream, so if we type a line containing only a comment, what the parser sees is exactly the same as what it sees when we type a blank line: just the EOL character.

So what's wrong with that? The grammar specifies what the input looks like:

```
calclist: /* Nothing */
 | calclist exp EOL { /* print answer */ }
```

It's important to understand what these rules mean, and this exercise is encouraging you to think about the meaning of these rules. You'll find a longer (and perhaps friendlier) explanation in John Levine's book (and in any other book about parsing), but the basic idea is quite simple. The rules say that a `calclist` is either empty, or it's a (previously identified) `calclist` followed by an `exp` followed by an `EOL`. No other possibilities exist.

How, then, could an empty line be matched? An empty line is just an `EOL`; there is no `exp`, so it won't match the second rule. (That's good, because we don't want to print a non-existent answer to an empty line.) Since there is nothing else, we need to add another rule:

```
 | calclist EOL { /* Do nothing */ }
```

Now, how will lines containing only a comment be handled? Why?

The above didn't touch the scanner at all, but exercise 1-1 suggests that there could be solution in the scanner, too. Could there? How complicated is it? Could it deal appropriately with blank lines? You might want to spend a bit of time trying to see how to do this with the scanner. It is possible, but it's nowhere near as simple as adding one line to the parser.

Comment: Thanks! Now I know the meaning of "fix":). About the solution of the scanner, I actually have no idea about that. I decided to keep reading. Thank you again.